# What is the standard Google Analytics UTM attribution method?

Tags: url, cookies, google-analytics, tracking, utm

Is it first/last click?

What is the standard duration until expiry?

Where can I see this information for a specific UTM-link I created and how can these settings be modified (both for existing as well as new UTM-links)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA collect ["hits"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086082?hl=en), these hits represent data/values at a specific instant in time (userid/source/medium/content/browser/etc..)

GA only report on the data. If you want to look at attribution, you're able to [adjust it yourself](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518?hl=en). It is flexible.

[Instructions on how to change session timeout and campaign expiry.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en) The default for sessions is 30mins and campaign expires after 6 months.

[Here is documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en) on how UTM parameters match up to GA data. You can usually find these under the Acquisition section of reports in GA.